# Qual o diminutivo de beija-flor?

Tags: diminutivos, composições

Dizemos ***um*** beija-flor, o diminutivo correto deveria ser:

- *um beija-florzinha* (que soa estranho)

ou

- *um beija-florzinho* (que suspeito estar errado mas acredito que seria a primeira coisa que viria à mente das pessoas.

**Update:**

Refletindo mais sobre o assunto, pensei em outro caso *um guarda-chuva*, em que para mim acontece o contrário: *um guarda-chuvinha* (soa muito mais natural) do que *um guarda-chuvinho*, embora, a meu ver (corrijam-me se estiver errada), ambos casos devem ter a mesma regra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Um beija-flor" se refere ao *pássaro* beija-flor, e não à *flor* que o pássaro "beija".
"Pássaro" é um substantivo masculino.

Portanto, seria "um beija-florzinho", um pequeno beija-flor.

Só poderia ser "beija-florzinh**a**" se:

1. "beija-florzinha" for separado, como em "Esse beija-flor beija florzinhas" (um beija-flor, de dimensões normais, que beija flores pequenas).
2. fosse o nome de uma espécie de beija-flor especializado em flores pequenas, como o Jacinto [disse](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/qual-o-diminutivo-de-beija-flor#answer-1089).
3. o beija-flor for fêmea, "A beija-florzinha voou para longe".

### Edit

Sobre o seu update acerca de "guarda-chuvinha" vs "guarda-chuvinho":

No português, o diminutivo na maioria dos substantivos pode ser tanto com "-zinho" quanto com "-inho". Guarda-chuva pode ser tanto "guarda-chu**vinha**" quanto "guarda-chu**vazinho**".

O diminutivo com -zinho sempre segue o gênero do mesmo, ou seja, "guarda-chuvazinho" é masculino porque guarda-chuva é de gênero masculino, a não ser que talvez em alguma fábula exista uma guarda-chuva fêmea. Do mesmo modo funciona beija-florzinho. Um exemplo de substantivo feminino: parede. Paredezinha é de gênero feminino porque parede é de gênero feminino.

Essa diferença de gêneros entre os diminutivos também acontece com outras palavras, como "tema": "teminh**a**" e "temazinh**o**". "Temazinh**o**" porque "tema" é masculino.

[Fonte](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/07/guarda-chuvinha/)

Comment: Eu concordo com isso tudo, mas no entanto chamo "seu pestinha" a um garoto!

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi o que você quis dizer. "Pestinha" vem de "peste" que é um substantivo feminino.

Comment: Mas se for um garoto eu digo _és um pestinha_.

Comment: @Jacinto   Sim, tu dirias "um pestinha", e eu também, porque creio que não existe "pestinho".  Quanto a resposta acima, eu também diria, sem mesmo pensar, "um beija-florzinho".  Da mesma forma, eu diria "um guarda-chuvazinho".

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, _guarda-chuvazinho_ é também como eu diria. Novamente, _guarda-chuvinha_ soa-me a um guarda-chuva para chuva ligeira.

Comment: @Jacinto Acho que o que acontece com "pestinha" é que, apesar de vir de "peste", que é feminino, "pestinha" se tornou um substantivo separado, de gênero masculino, ao invés de ser apenas o diminutivo de "peste".

Comment: Com esse edit ficou muito boa a resposta. =)

Comment: @BrunoLopes  Acho que pestinha pode ser usado para os dois gêneros: um pestinha e uma pestinha.

Answer (score 4):

Beija-flor, dicionario:

> bei·ja·-flor |ô|
>   substantivo masculino
>
> [Ornitologia]  Pequeno pássaro tenuirrostro de formosa plumagem, com bico fino e longo, usado para sugar o néctar das flores. = CHUPA-FLOR, CHUPA-MEL, COLIBRI, PICA-FLOR
>
> ```
> "beija-flor", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, 
> http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/beija-flor [consultado em 09-09-2015].
> ```

[Diminutivo](http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/rv1ti):

> As palavras terminadas em sílaba tônica, ditongos nasais, vogal tônica, já é sabido que formam o diminutivo em '-zinho':

Portanto o diminutivo obedece a inflexão de gênero para o masculino, **terminamos o diminutivo em O**; Caso esteja redigindo uma fábula com um beija-flor fêmea, pode-se inflexionar para o feminino por motivo de gênero da personagem.

Por "flor" ser monossílabo (e termina em sílaba tônica), temos o diminutivo:

> beija-florzinho

Beija é originário de verbo, e não sofre inflexão para o diminutivo.

Comment: Creio que compreendeste mal a tua fonte. O que ela diz é que nos casos indicados acima se usa **zinho** em vez de **inho**; não diz que se usa **zinho** em vez de **zinha**. Como podemos ver por um exemplo. **Mãe** acaba em ditongo nasal, um dos caso mencionados acima. Mas obviamente é **mãezinha**.

Comment: @Jacinto Nestes casos usa-se a concordância de gênero. Por isto abro com o dicionário: `beija-flor s.m.`, logo `-zinho`. Caso esteja redigindo uma fábula com um beija-flor fêmea, pode-se inflexionar para o feminino pelo gênero da personagem. "A beija-florzinh**a** Josefina acordou em uma bela manhã de primavera(...)"

Comment: Compreendido. Com a tua redação anterior fiquei com a ideia que era a terminação em sílaba tónica que justificava o masculino. De qualquer modo, no fundo do artigo, são apresentados como possíveis diminutivos de flor quer florzinha quer florinha (por flor terminar em consoante), Mas eu gosto mais de beija-florzinho do que beija-florinho. Onde encontraste a regra da concordância de género? Eu já chamei  _seu pestinha_ a garotos.

Comment: @Jacinto `Peste - substantivo feminino` diminutivo, pestinha. Mesmo quando aplicado a pessoas do sexo masculino. "sua peste". http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pestinha  `7. [Informal]  Pessoa irrequieta ou travessa (ex.: aquele garoto é uma peste!).

"pestinha", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pestinha [consultado em 09-09-2015].`

Answer (score 2):

Para mim, é um *beija-florzinho*; e um *beija-florzinha* seria um beija-flor especializado em flores pequeninas.

Comment: Eu penso da mesma forma. Mas... essa é só sua (nossa) opinião, ou você tem alguma evidência de que essa é a forma correta?

Comment: Não tenho evidência nenhuma; apenas uma arrogância desmesurada :) Mesmo assim, ainda comecei a minha resposta com um "para mim". Acho pouco provável que haja uma regra definida. E se somos pelo menos três (incluindo a autora da questão) a achar estranho _um beija-florzinha_... e ninguém a manifestar sentimento contrário... E em último recurso podemos invocar liberdade poética.

Comment: Opinião expressa em 1 frase fica melhor como comentário.

Comment: Eu não acho, @brasofilo , porque acho que é uma resposta (fraquinha ou não). Ao passar o rato por cima de *"add a comment"*, aparece: `Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.`

Comment: Eu mantenho a resposta. É uma opinião com algum fundamento: a alternativa a beija-florzinho, beija-florzinha, não serve porque sugere um beija-flor especializado em flores pequenas.